# цель задачи: нужно спарсить один сайт и вывести pdf файл пользователю, код написал но не получается присоединить парсер к боту

Tags: python, парсер, telegram-bot, requests, aiogram

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton
import os

storage = MemoryStorage()
TOKEN= 'token'
bot = Bot(token='TOKEN')
dp: Dispatcher = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

async def on_startup(_):
    print('Бот вышел онлайн')


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
async def comand_start(message: types.message):
    try:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Привет')
        await message.delete()
    except:
        await message.reply('общение с ботом')

from aiogram.types import ParseMode
from aiogram.types import file
from aiogram.types import Document
@dp.message_handler(commands=['Расписание пар для студентов'])
async def raspisanie(message: types.Message):
    await bot.parse_mode(parsing(message.from_user.id))


# Кнопки

b1 = KeyboardButton('/Расписание пар для студентов')
kb_client = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)

kb_client.add(b1)

#parsing
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


async def parsing():
    link = "https://www.tpk-tver.ru/studentam-i-obuchyushchimsya/raspisanie-zanyatij.html"
    responce = requests.get(f'{link}').text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(responce, 'lxml')
    block1 = soup.find(class_="odd")
    block2 = block1.find_next(class_="odd")
    block3 = block2.find_next(class_="odd")
    block4 = block3.find_next(class_="odd")
    block5 = block4.find_next(class_="odd")
    block6 = block5.find(class_="at_url")
    link1 = "https://www.tpk-tver.ru"
    imag = block6.get('href')
    down = requests.get(f'{link1}{imag}').content
    with open(f'if.pdf', 'wb') as file:
            file.write(down)


executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский. Вы это можете, судя по надписям в коде.

Comment: Не очень понятно что вам нужно, что значит присоединить парсер к боту? В чем сложность? В том чтобы вызвать одну функцию внутри другой? Как именно вы его собираетесь присоединить? Где у вас меню или команды в боте?